# Description of first item in product list would not shown

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, product-list

At the product list the custom description build on attributes in a static block would shown at the first item (product). At the other items it would show up as I wish.

At this page: http://tinyurl.com/qfqr233

What I'm doing wrong?

```
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');

?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php //if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>
    <?php if(true): ?>
    <?php $_iterator = 0; ?>
    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
    <?
        // Car Attributes
        $merknaam       = $_product->getAttributeText('merknaam');
        $automerk       = $_product->getAttributeText('auto_merk');
        $automodel      = $_product->getAttributeText('auto_type');
        $autotype       = $_product->getAttributeText('car_type');
        $bouwjaar       = $_product->getAutoBouwjaarText();
        $daktype        = $DakLinkTrans .$_product->getAttributeText('dakdragers_dakreling'). '</a>';
        $daktypehome    = $_product->getAttributeText('dakdragers_dakreling');
        $product        = $_product->getAttributeText('product_type');

        // Load static Block
        $short_block    = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('short_block_'.$product.'')->toHtml();

        // Load Block
        $DakLinkTrans       = '<a href="/' .$_product->getAttributeText('dakdragers_dakreling'). '" rel="iframeLink" title="Meer informatie over dit daktype">';
        $DakTypeValue       = array('Met gesloten dakrailing', 'Glad dak', 'Montage op de originele punten', 'T-profiel', 'Open dakrailing', 'Regengoot');
        $DakTypeLinks       = array('daktype-gesloten-dakrailing', 'daktype-glad-dak', 'daktype-montage-originele-punten', 'daktype-t-profiel', 'daktype-open-dakrailing', 'daktype-regengoot');
        $DakLinkTrans       = str_replace($DakTypeValue, $DakTypeLinks, $DakLinkTrans);

        $AutoTextVars       = array('{{merknaam}}', '{{auto_merk}}', '{{auto_model}}', '{{auto_type}}', '{{bouwjaar}}', '{{daktype}}', '{{product_type}}');

        $AutoAttrVars       = array($merknaam, $automerk, $automodel, $autotype, $bouwjaar, $daktype, $product);
        $AutoAttrVarsHome   = array($merknaam, $automerk, $automodel, $autotype, $bouwjaar, $daktypehome, $product);
        ?>
        <li class="item<?php if( ++$_iterator == sizeof($_productCollection) ): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
            <?php // Product Image ?>
            <?php /*
            <div class="onsale-category-container-list">
                <?php echo Mage::helper('onsale')->getCategoryLabelHtml($_product); ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
            </div>
            */?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
           <?php // Product description ?>
            <div class="product-shop">
                <div class="f-fix">
                    <?php $_productNameStripped = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true); 

                    ?>
                    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_productNameStripped; ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="desc std">
                        <?php //echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getShortDescription(), 'short_description') 

                            if(!Mage::getSingleton('cms/page')->getIdentifier() == 'home') : 
                                echo str_replace($AutoTextVars, $AutoAttrVars, $short_block);
                            else:
                                echo str_replace($AutoTextVars, $AutoAttrVarsHome, $short_block);
                            endif;
                        ?>
                    </div>


                    <?php $levertijd = $_product->getAttributeText('levertijd_short'); ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($levertijd)): ?>

                        <div class="levertijdcat">
                            <div class="review-categorie">
                                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                            <div class="levering">
                                <span><?php echo $levertijd; ?></span>
                            </div>

                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <p><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="Meer informatie over <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>" id="buttonmore" class="newbutton btn-cart orange mediumbutton">Meer informatie</a></p>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="Meer informatie over <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>" id="buttonmore" class="newbutton btn-cart orange mediumbutton">Meer informatie</a></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>

                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
                        <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
                            <div class="review-categorie">
                                <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product) ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="Meer informatie over <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>" id="buttonmore" class="newbutton btn-cart orange mediumbutton">Meer informatie</a></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="Meer informatie over <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name'); ?>" id="buttonmore" class="newbutton btn-cart orange mediumbutton">Meer informatie</a></p>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                    <?php  endif; ?>
                    <ul class="add-to-links">
                        <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                            <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                            <li><span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>

    <?php else: ?>

    <?php // Grid Mode ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is found!

By moving down the var of static block, it will load the attributes into the block. In the case the block was loaded before the attributes were loaded.